# MVC Web Api as a middle tier service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In our recent application we are planning to use MVC Web API as a Middler tier service. Meaning, front end will access the WebAPI middler tier service to get all the data it required from DB and to update the data back to DB. Along with this there may be many other methods that we will need. For example check whether user already exists in the system, Validate the address, etc. Now I have come into a point that my webapiconfig.cs routing is becoming more complex. For example my UserController in WebApi project will have following methods.

> public User Get(int userId)
>           {
>           }

```
    public bool IsUserExists(string username)
    {
    }

    public bool UpdateUser([FromBody]User user)
    {
    }

    public bool ChangePassword(string username, string password)
    {
    }
```

To manage all of these I may need so many routing configurations in webapiconfig.cs. I am not sure how to deal with these when other controllers comes to the picture. Should I use AttributeRouting? Any suggestion highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option to use [web api 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448365%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) go for [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). You can save your lot of development effort in configuring routes.

Also make sure you are following resource based routing design and REST principles, than old RPC style routes. i.e for basic CRUD operations :-

- Create - `HTTP POST` to `/user`
- Read -   `HTTP GET` to `/user` or `/user/{id}`
- Update - `HTTP PUT` to `/user`
- Delete - `HTTP DELETE` to `/user/{id}`

For example for updating an user

Instead of route `/user/UpdateUser`

You should do a

```
HTTPPUT to /user/
```

For more tips on REST check [this](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restquicktips.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply. So whenever possible I should use RESTful services and for other situations attribute routing (web api 2). For methods like IsUserExists/ChangePassword I have to rely with attribute routing. When comparing with WCF, eventhough it adds SOAP and other complexities, do you think it is better to use WCF for the middle tier? (a separately hosted services layer)

Comment: Please note that asp.net web api an architecture which helps to buid REST service in simpler way. if you require only http based service why not using web api itself.also for methods like change password you can create url like /user/{userid}/password-change

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the last part. Is "password-change" is a action method in UserController?